# Saving a watchlist for each user in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, data-structures, database-design, architecture

In the laravel project I'm currently working on I want to store watchlists of contents for each user.

I'm wondering now what is the best way to do it, I came up with adding a column to the users table named watchlist and then store a json string in there containing all contents on the watchlist of that user.

But I feel like this is the most simple and basic way to do it. Is there any better/ more elegant way to do it? FYI: I use mysql.

Answer (score 1):

if the list items comes from another columns, i prefer to put the user watchlist in table instead of putting in on a json, because of cascading or any future update.

Comment: But how do I manage new contents being added or deleted. I mean it would be very impractical to add new columns whenever adding new items to the watchlist

Comment: I agree with Ahmed Ali, That's a more practical and scalable approach in my opinion too.